# How to add Add button to enter dynamic value in Angular 2/4/6/8 Multiselect Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to add dynamic add button angular2 multiselect. Any one has done this dynamic addition of user entered value by selecting Plus button. I have tried with addNewItemOnFilter: true, I'm not able to see any + button.

I am putting (onAddFilterNewItem)="onAddItem($event)" for using angular2-multiSelect.

In settings, I am having
 addNewItemOnFilter: true in the settings file.

Still I am not getting an extra 'ADD' button to add extra field. Any help I would appreciate.

Comment: Please share your minimum effort code

Answer (score 0):

There You have dynamic multiselect buttons.

**Updated as you want input inside.**

**Template:**

```html
<div *ngIf="buttons" class="btn-group">
    <button *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="addDynaminMultiseletButton()">
        {{button}} <input type="text" (click)="setInput($event)">
    </button>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
buttons = ['Another button']
input: string

constructor() { }

addDynaminMultiseletButton() {
  this.buttons.push("" + this.input)
}

setInput(event: any) {
  this.input = event.target.value
}
```

**You can store them in database:**

```
buttons$ = Observable<any[]>

constructor(private db: SomeDatabase){}

ngOnInit() {
   this.buttons = this.db.collection('fancyButtons').valueChanges()
}

addDynaminMultiseletButton() {
    this.db.collection('fancyButtons').add({ fancyButton: 'fancyButton' })
}
```

Remember to subscribe when you want to display async buttons:

**Template:**

```html
<div *ngIf="buttons$ | async as buttons " class="btn-group">
    <button *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="addDynaminMultiseletButton()">+</button>
</div>
```

Have a nice day and **good luck** with programming! Remember to assign at least one element in array so there will be at least one button on screen.

Comment: Thanks @Mises. I am using <angular2-multiselect > package. Do you have any idea to get extra text field in it?

Comment: @SaratChandra Updated answer for you. But no database option sorry.